# Python : calling a function inside a while loop results in runaway recursion

Tags: python, while-loop, function-calls

I have written a Python function `randomizer()` that randomizes the lines from a file and then writes them to std output. On its own, it works without problems. Now I want to be able to iterate this process a user-defined number of times, so I write:

```
def iterator():
    print("Number of iterations: ")
    total_iterations = raw_input()
    current_iteration = 1
    while current_iteration <= total_iterations:
        randomizer()
        current_iteration = current_iteration + 1
```

If I do this, `randomizer()` just keeps on repeating itself until I manually terminate it. However, if the while loop is

```
while current_iteration <= total_iterations:
    random.shuffle(listname)
    current_iteration = current_iteration + 1
```

then `iterator()` stops after the specified number of runs. The same problem arises if I write the entire code of `randomizer()` inside the while loop of `iterator()`. This tells me that there is a problem with calling a function from inside a while loop, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: That should be giving you an error unless the extra indentation is a typo.

Comment: yes, the extra indent was a typo on the question (corrected now), but not on my code.

Comment: Does the second version really work? The problem is that the result of `raw_input()` is a string, not an int, so the condition never terminates.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thank you. The following works: `while current_iteration <= int(total_iterations):

Comment: @user1559769 you should do the conversion outside the loop, not in the test condition

Comment: BTW, in python you can avoid extra typing with  ...   current_iteration += 1

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `raw_input()` returns a string and so the comparison `while current_iteration <= total_iterations` always returns true.

Fix by casting to an int

```
total_iterations = int(raw_input())
```